# Helper method running afoul of Mass Assignment security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mass-assignment

I typically write something like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name

  def name
    "#{ first_name } #{ last_name }"
  end

  def name=(str)
    first, last = str.split(' ', 2)
    write_attribute :first_name, first
    write_attribute :last_name, last
  end
end
```

Which allows you to do `Person.new(:name => "Adam Lassek")` instead of splitting it up in the controller.

In Rails 3.1.0.rc4-5, this gives me the `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name` error.

This used to work. What changed?

Comment: I think you just need to add name to the attr_accessible

Comment: @Matt tried that; didn't work.

Comment: @Matt scratch that; looks like it does work, it was not being applied for an unrelated reason.

Comment: @Matt add an answer below so I can mark it

Comment: cool. Added below as a short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add name to the attr_accessible